# Align or flat an image left of its immediate parent div only

Tags: html, css

I have a div 'container' which holds all my content and  is set for 80% width. Inside that div I have div 'tophead' which contains a logo and a nav bar at 100% (but it only reaches the parent 80%). Then I have 'maincont' which is inside the 'container' div and has an image. Id like this image to be left aligned with the side of the 'container' div so that there is still that 20% space left open. If I float left or align left it shows up all the way to the left of the screen over the 20% id like blank. Any idea how to fix this would be very much appreciated.

Bonus thanks if someone can figure out why the image overlaps my nav bar.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4JKus/4/

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ccoheader.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div align="center" id="tophead">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Biographies">Biographies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="maincont">
        <img src="images/secondimage.png" alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}

#tophead {
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;

}

#tophead img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto%;
}
#tophead ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;

}
#tophead li {
    display: inline-block;

    }
#tophead a {
  background: #2dbaf0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "arial";
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;

}
#tophead a:hover {
  background: #f8a52b;
  color: #fff;
}
#tophead li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#tophead li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#maincont {
    height: 68%;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 2%;

    }
#maincont img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how far this gets to solving your problem(s), but its a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JKus/5/

Using the align attribute in div declarations is considered bad form.  You had a stray /div hanging out.  Not sure why you are forcing your images and the main container to 100% height.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ccoheader.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="tophead">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Biographies">Biographies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="maincont">
            <div class="maincont_col1">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="maincont_col2">
                <img src="images/secondimage.png" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#tophead {
    height: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;

}

#tophead img {
    width: auto%;
}
#tophead ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;

}
#tophead li {
    display: inline-block;

    }
#tophead a {
  background: #2dbaf0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "arial";
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;

}
#tophead a:hover {
  background: #f8a52b;
  color: #fff;
}
#tophead li:first-child a {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#tophead li:last-child a {
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#maincont {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;

    }
.maincont_col1{ width:20%; float:left; }
.maincont_col2{ width:80%; float:left; }

#maincont img{
    border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: First I appreciate your response. I'm new as in yesterday new to html and css so please feel free to point out my mistakes and I apologize in advance if they seem idiotic. 

I was using the percentages on the images because they are big files. I was told that site might be used on a HDTV so i thought it best to keep the header at 20% and put the image in there at 100% of that 20 so that if its on a computer screen it would look small but scale well on a TV. Bad idea?

I used the align attribute because i couldnt get the content centered. What would be the preferable way?

Comment: No worries, your doing a great job so far with HTML/CSS.  It takes a while to find best practices in any syntax you pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of `float:left` in your `#maincont img` selector solves the first problem.

Problem 2 is down to the fact that you have a topheader of 20% and the nav bar overlaps this..  You can fix this by removing the stipulation that the top and bottom are fixed in size.

Comment: If i take out the float left the image is being centered because (as the above post pointed out) i used a bad form align=center in the div tag. I did that to center the content because i couldn't figure out any other way for it to be centered. What would be the preferable method of centering just that one div (tophead) and not the other content in the other divs?

Comment: The float left doesn't center the image for me...it is left aligned when I remove the float:left rule.